# relationship of 3 tables in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, query-builder

Given that I have 3 tables: user, competences and competences_user, how can I get the list of skills of each user with query-builder?

Table structures:

- user: id, nom....
- competences: id, titre...
- competences_user : id, competence_id, user_id...

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
select user.id, user.nom, competences.titre
FROM user
  Inner Join competences_user 
     ON = competences_user.competence_id AND user.id = competence_user.user_id
  Inner Join competences
     ON competences.id = competence_user.competence_id
```

Comment: @ Nablie Inner Join competences_user ON = competences_user.competence_id    why there is this     =     in this place ?

Comment: I reworded and reformatted the question to make it easier to read.  I also broke up the query code so that one does not need to side-scroll in order to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many ways to do it , the easy way without the query builder :

ie :

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
        ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
        ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
        ->get();
```

To answer your question :

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('competences_user', 'competences_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('competences', 'competences_user.competence_id', '=', 'competences.id')
        ->select('users.*', 'competences.titre')
        ->get();
```

You can refer to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins) for more details.

Comment: @ Fadil It works, but apparently it is necessary to separate the query to 2, because each user has multiple skills

Comment: Not necessary, the query will return multiple lines if exists.

Comment: Thank you, I come back to you after the test!

Comment: @nabil You can also grab data by using `DB::table('competences')->join(...)->join(...)->select(...)->where('user.id', '=', '1')` for example

Comment: please more detail, with exemple

Comment: @nabil can you tell me what's wrong with `$users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('competences_user', 'competences_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('competences', 'competences_user.competence_id', '=', 'competences.id')
        ->select('users.*', 'competences.titre')
        ->get();` ? it didn't answer your question ?

Comment: @fadil sorry, I do a mistake in the source code, I will come back later to you!

Comment: Ok sure, but please close this if it's answer to your question, open another one if you have more questions.